# Can't build assets on deploy - Symfony 5/Encore/Ux

Tags: symfony, deployment, build, assets, webpack-encore

I have a **Symfony 5 application**, i'm using **webpack Encore / Ux** for the first time.
I'm facing difficulties with deployment, only the HTML is displayed at the URL ; the "build" directory is almost empty, it only contains "entrypoints.json" and "manifest.json". the assets aren't compiled.
When im running **npm run build to compile the assets in production** i have this message :

sh: encore: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ build: `encore production --progress`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

**The build script in the package.json doesnt work** :
"scripts": {
"dev-server": "encore dev-server",
"dev": "encore dev",
"watch": "encore dev --watch",
"build": "encore production --progress"
}

and i have no idea to where does this come from.
Would someone have something for this ?

i ran npm run build and it doesnt work, but it does in dev mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before** deploying to production server you need to *Compile Assets for Production on your dev server*.
Then deploy only the built assets.

The process is documented here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-deploy-my-encore-assets

Comment: i ve tried this earlier and had no results, and i thought it was optionnal. It did resolved the problem, thanks for helping !